# HERE maps autosuggestion does not return expected results from downloaded map package while offline

Tags: here-api, here-ios

Environment: HERE iOS SDK, version 3.13.2, account is "Freemium", but credentials are set up as "Premium"

We are using NMAPlaces - createAutoSuggestionRequest to provide user with location suggestions as they type. We would like to support this feature in offline mode too.
And so we implemented offline mode, using NMAMapLoader.
But while in offline mode, i.e. no internet connection is available, NMAPlaces does not return expected suggestion results.

Example: application has downloaded NMAMapPackage for Nevada state, and is in offline mode - no internet connection is available. When we try to type in "las vegas" - autosuggestion does not list this city. It list some results like "98th Av:Las Vegas Av" and "Las Vegas Rd, Orinda, CA" without geo coordinates - if that matters.
Request does not returns any errors on start or completion.

As soon we turn on network connection, app can find "las vegas" just fine.

We have tried setting request.connectivity to offline/online , but it gives the same results as just turning network off/on.

Q: Is it possible to make offline autosuggestions with HERE SDK? If yes, what can we do to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Can you find other city names? Getting no geo coordinates should be ok, as (offline) autosuggestions only provides strings

Comment: @ctrlw - Nope, I have tried about a dozen of the most known and biggest cities from downloaded region - no luck. I'm getting mostly street names, as far as I can tell, sometimes places, like "University of _", but not that city in general.

Comment: Anyway, if offline autosuggestion does not provide coordinates, then it's no use for us, because we need coordinates as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK Offline maps do provide autosuggestion feature. For more details please check the following documentation.

- https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-data.html
- https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/MapDownloader.zip

Comment: Just noticed, that ATM autosuggestion marked as beta feature without offline support. Is it really possible to do NMAAutoSuggestionRequest in offline mode?